# Stopping transparent drawing going all the way through NSViews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, drawing, nsview

I'm doing some simple drawing in my NSView's drawRect with code like this

```
[[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.250 alpha:0.700] set];
NSRectFill(dRect);
```

This drawing is being done in a nested view and I'm finding that the transparency goes all the way through the parent view and window showing some of the screen beneath it.

How do I get it so the transparency only goes through to the parent view (or any drawing that was done in that frame before it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using NSRectFill to draw a transparent color. A call to

```
NSRectFill(rect);
```

is really just a shortcut to

```
NSRectFillUsingOperation(rect, NSCompositeCopy);
```

NSCompositeCopy doesn't perform compositing, so you can get unexpected results when a transparent NSColor is set.

Try using this instead:

```
[[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.250 alpha:0.700] set];
[NSBezierPath fillRect:rect];
```

That should draw the transparency properly, with the underlying drawing visible.